# Phonegap: new FileTransfer(); returns undefined

Tags: android, cordova, file-transfer

i want to download a file in phonegap using FileTransfer, but i only get a "ReferenceError: FileTransfer is not defined" error (line 3 on the below code).
I am using phonegap 3.3.0; File and FileTransfer plugins are already added to config.xml(and showing on build.phonegap.com).
I am building via web interface

```
function DescargaRepo2(id) {
    try {
        var fileDownloadEdit = new FileTransfer();
        alert("hecho: " + fileDownloadEdit);
    } catch (e) {
        alert("El error de FileTransfer es: " + e);
    }
    var uri = encodeURI("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/97184921/editme.txt");
    var filepath = "www/data/";
    fileDownloadEdit.download(
    uri, filepath, function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
        alert("File Downloaded. Click 'Read Editable Downloaded File' to see text");
    }, function(error) {
        //alert("download error source " + error.source);
        //alert("download error target " + error.target);
        alert("error code" + error.code);
    });
}
```

Comment: Solved-> http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap_new_filetransfer_returns_undefined?utm_source=notification&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=new_reply&utm_content=reply_button&reply[id]=14197619#reply_14197619